# Developer survey feedback: add an option for Occupied Palestinian Territory, or State of Palestine

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

Currently, 138 of the 193 United Nations (UN) member states and two non-member states have recognized Palestine. Stack Overflow's developer survey recognizes Hong Kong and Taiwan (which is recognized by fewer than 20 member states). These are far more internationally contentious.

[image: Developer Survey]

Stack Overflow should recognize the Occupied Palestinian Territory in its member survey too. This term is accepted by The United Nations, the European Union, International Committee of the Red Cross, and the government of the United Kingdom. [This is also the official name with ISO](https://web.archive.org/web/20110722001642/http://www.iso.org/iso/newsletter_v-2_palestinian_territory_occupied.pdf), before it was changed to the State of Palestine, which is also acceptable.

Comment: Your quarrel's with [Qualtrics](https://www.qualtrics.com/). That's not the first time similar things happen: [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393664/11407695), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379318/11407695), and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361661/11407695)

Comment: @OlegValter that's not true, the first link is about the survey being blocked in a country, the second is about a server error, neither of which are content related. The third link is about content and disagrees with exactly what you're concluding: **it explicitly shows the entrance of Taiwan on user request from this very website.**

Comment: All I am saying is that the issue you are having is with the survey provider, not the SE proper. Doesn't diminish your request, just an off-note. As for the linked questions, those are about issues with the provider over the years, not necessarily 1:1 mappings to your question.

Comment: @OlegValter why do you think that's the case though. I'm confused. The survey provider doesn't create the questions... Surely they have no idea what "Rust" even is. They just provide a platform for StackOverflow to create a survey, and a data analytics pipeline to analyze that data.

Comment: While I'm disinclined to close-hammer this I feel like the [MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407914/take-the-2021-developer-survey/407919#comment845289_407919) might be both a more appropriate place, and a better place to get attention to the issue

Comment: Well, I think it does need some clarification - they have predefined questions that companies can choose from - and something tells me the country list one was [one of them](https://www.qualtrics.com/community/discussion/639/how-to-create-country-dropdown-with-qualtrics). I mentioned them because they are the reason why the reminder "Qualtrics blocks certain countries from accessing their site and data" popups every year as well. Doesn't mean your question is invalid in any way - I suppose the absence is due to a certain country both orgs belong to refusing to recognize the state...

Comment: I don't think who Qualtrics prevents from _accessing_ the survey has anything to do with the content of the survey, including the country list. The country list is almost certainly provided by StackExchange. At the very least, presenting it as a question is shown to work as that third link follows the same form as this one here and got the issue resolved.

Comment: Again I don't see any thing substantiating your conclusion from [that source](https://www.qualtrics.com/community/discussion/639/how-to-create-country-dropdown-with-qualtrics). One answer is just use Multiple Choice and fill out the list of the countries. The other is to use a drill down list and also fill it out. The third is to "import" the question and presumably you can edit it before you import it or after, as it's still just a regular question.

Comment: I think we have a bit of a misunderstanding here - I don't have anything against your question or the validity of the request (well, maybe only in the sense that I think Journeyman Geek is right in pointing to a direct feedback post - that may prove more effective). SE most likely can add custom content and will if they notice this one - but as confirmed by the answer from 2018 I [linked to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361699/11407695), they are "using the default list of countries from our survey tool (Qualtrics)", that was *the only* meaning of the "Your quarrel's with Qualtrics".

Comment: Ah I follow now. The request here is only that the list be modified then for our needs. Obviously, I realize StackExchange is not a good place to petition Qualtrics.

Comment: Better asked on politics.stackexchange perhaps?

Comment: @Vérace - they don't run the Stack Overflow Developer Survey, and this question is about it :) Not that the OP cares right now - they got suspended till 2022 for some reason shortly after the post (I guess because of the username and/or avatar)...

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this question was closed as off-topic? Strange being the meta of meta of all sites. How could it be off-topic? On a side note: It has come to my attention that OP is in fact a Jew. Does that shift the perspective on their statement made in their profile name? And the resulting ban?

Comment: Also, if this question *is* off-topic for Meta.SE, where *exactly* would it be *on-topic*?

Comment: To add some context, by the letter, according to the MSE [\[survey\] tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/survey/info), "most" SO Dev Survey questions should be posted on MSO, not here (I realize that this is inconvenient for those without an existing SO account, however). I don't really see any reason this particular one should've been closed though, especially given the upvotes/ generally favorable response.

Comment: This question has since been reposted by someone else in OP's stead [over on the MSO Survey Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407914/take-the-2021-developer-survey/407960#407960).

Comment: Some questions are not on-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange. It has always been clear that we have sites for specific areas of expertise, and that we explicitly reject the claim that we can or should have a place for every question. Issues with the content of a third party service provider should be directed to that provider.

Comment: @JohnK.N. Do you actually also have information about the reasons for the ban? Anyway, why would the user's religion/nationality affect it?